# Batch for Add Folder to Multiple rar files

Tags: batch-file

All anyone can share the code for folder to add into existing rar.
i have a folder which contains some files
for eg Xref(Folder) which contains some dwg files
So, this folder i have to add Number of Rar files.
Like => `0001-a.rar , 0002-a.rar , 0003-a.rar`

i can move the files by use below code :

```
for %%I in ("C:\Users\prasanna\Desktop\New folder (9)\New folder (2).rar") do "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -ep -idq -y -m0 "%%~I" "C:\Users\prasanna\Desktop\New folder (9)\New.txt"
for %%I in ("C:\Users\prasanna\Desktop\New folder (9)\New folder.rar") do "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -ep -idq -y -m0 "%%~I" "C:\Users\prasanna\Desktop\New folder (9)\New.txt"
```

Comment: I am not getting your question, please edit it and clarify what you want.

Comment: thank you @gerhard, My Question is simple how to add folder into existing rar file.

Comment: I Found the Solution for %%I in ("C:\Users\prasanna\Desktop\New folder (9)\Test1.rar") do "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r -idq -y -m0 "%%~I" "New" "New2"

Comment: So I suggest you delete your question then `:)`

Answer (score 0):

finally got it.

```
for %%I in ("C:\Users\prasanna\Desktop\New folder (9)\Test1.rar") do "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r -idq -y -m0 "%%~I" "New" "New2"
```